# Unable to load the windows driver

Tags: windows-10, driver, wdk, kmdf

I was trying to load the windows driver in windows 10 using [OSR Loader](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm%5Earticle=157.htm), the service for `HelloWorld.sys` has been created, but when I click on start, it's saying "This driver has been blocked from loading"

The video I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nc-uh8O989I

Upon investigating,

- Driver compatibility issue → I tried set Target OS to Windows10 (Universal and then to Desktop)
- Driver signature enforcement issue → ran `bcdedit.exe /set nointegritychecks on`
- WDK might not be supported → Followed this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjZVkuKQzTk&t=141s
- Signing issue → ran `bcdedit /set testsigning on`
- Tried testing from `sc.exe` command → `sc create HelloWorld binpath=/my/sys/file type=kernel && sc start HelloWorld`

Comment: Also, I tried using `devcon install HelloWorld.inf root\HelloWorld`, it says `devcon.exe failed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was,

Target PC: Windows 10 Home **x64** 
Kernel Mode Driver Target: Windows 10 Desktop **x86**

**NOTE:** The kernel build architecture must match the target machine architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this in case someone runs into the same error, but from a different use case.  I was trying to find out cpu information running sysinternals CoreInfo executable as admin from a command prompt:

```
coreinfo.exe -v command. //The 32 bit system command.
```

> Coreinfo v3.6 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
> Copyright (C) 2008-2022 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals -
> [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)
>
> Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-10855M CPU @ 2.80GHz Intel64 Family 6 Model 165
> Stepping 2, GenuineIntel Microcode signature: 000000EC Error loading
> driver: **This driver has been blocked from loading**

I used the set pro command from the same command prompt to verify 64 bit:

```
C:\>set pro
```

PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=a502
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
**ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files**
PROMPT=$P$G

However, because I have a 64bit system, this was the correct command and output:

```
C:\> coreinfo64.exe -v
```

> Coreinfo v3.6 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
> Copyright (C) 2008-2022 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals -
> [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)
>
> Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-10855M CPU @ 2.80GHz Intel64 Family 6 Model 165
> Stepping 2, GenuineIntel Microcode signature: 000000EC HYPERVISOR
> `enter code here`-       Hypervisor is present VMX

- ```
    Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization EPT
  ```
- ```
    Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT) URG
  ```
- ```
    Supports Intel unrestricted guest
  ```

I needed to find out if my CPU supported SLAT mentioned above so I could install Docker.